# split() / in вхождение

Tags: python

Пользователь вводит строку произвольной длины. Затем пользователь вводит слово. Определить входит ли в строку переданное пользователем слово (учитывая, что слова могут начинаться с большой буквы).

Подскажите какую строку я потерял и где?

```
text = input("enter split:")
text_2 = input("enter")
print(f'{text.split()}{text_2.split()}')
if text in text_2:
    print('входит ')
```

притом надпись 'входит он не затрагивает'
Я так понимаю я пропустил где то upper()?

Comment: `if text.upper() in text_2.upper()` ?

Comment: да.... немного не то

Comment: text = input("enter split: ")
print(f'{text.split()}')
text_2 = input("enter word: ")
print(f'{text_2.split()}')
for text in text_2:
    if text<text_2:
        print('t')
    elif text>text_2:
        print('f')
только сравниваются тут символы или вхождения?

Comment: я не понял что вы хотели сказать вашими комментариями...

Comment: да я upper() написал лишними...забудьте про него 
ниже вывод переделанного 
Ну нужно сравнить не символы а вхождение слова в предложение(строку)

Comment: уточните вопрос и желательно привести в вопросе примеры строк и слов... Например входит ли слово `раз` в строку `кровожадные разбойники`?

Comment: в input сначала вводиться строка, затем вводиться слово ...нужно определить входит ли слово в строку

Comment: `входит ли слово в строку` - не является достаточным условием. Что есть слово и строка? Что должна вернуть ваша программа если пользователь введет `"стол"` в качестве слова и `"Апостол Нафанаил"` в качестве строки?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
text_1, text_2 = input(), input()
text_1 = text_1.lower()
print(text_1.find(text_2.lower()))
```

если найдет, выдаст начало вхождения в строку, если нет, выведет -1